# R Fitting curves using mean values, standard deviation and N

Tags: r, function, curve-fitting, mean, standard-deviation

Normally I use individual data for curve fitting e.g.

```
X <- c( 0, 0, 0, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 5.8, 5.8, 5.8, ...)
Y <- c( 99, 98, 101, 80, 72, 77, 55, 40, 46, ...)
```

Then I create a dataframe and use any fitting function provided in R.

```
drm(Y~X, data = dataframe, fct = L.3(), type="continuous")
```

But now I only have the mean, standard deviation and the number of values (N) FOR EACH LEVEL OF X AND Y.

I search a while but couldn't find a function which has means, sd and N as input.

My questions are:

Is there a function which can calculate with means etc.?

Or, is it possible to transform the mean values back to individual values?

Thanks in advance

Alunius

Comment: Are you trying to fit a curve, or to fit a statistical distribution? I don't understand how you would fit a curve with just the mean and standard deviation.

Comment: You cannot transform the mean back to individual values if you don't have residuals.

Comment: In addition to the marginal summary statistics, you would need to know the covariance of x and y to fit a simple linear regression line.

Comment: OP: I want to fit a curve. A Dose-Response-Curve. I used a R package called "Proast" and there it was possible to insert means and standard deviations. "Proast" then uses exponential and Hill models to fit the data. So somehow it should work.

At the end I only want to be able to do exactly what "Proast" do but with different models.

Comment: It works if you know the functional form of the distribution. For instance, a normal distribution is fully characterized by its variance and mean. But if you don't know anything about the functional form of your distribution, the mean won't help you getting it back. You cannot condensate a function to one or two numbers without loss of information.

Comment: OP: @RHertel: I understand what you mean. Thanks. Since, I only have means from one single dose and from one repeated experiment, I'm 99% sure I always have a normal distribution.

Comment: So you have the summary statistics for y for each level of x? You should edit your question to reflect that - at least I got the impression that you just had the overall summary statistics for x and y, which would be a completely different situation.

Comment: I don't understand what you have the mean and stdev of.  "FOR EACH LEVEL OF X AND Y" makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

The experimental package "toxReviewer" in github is specialized for analyzing toxicological data in summary form. It does not yet work with install_git().  It also does not have dose response models at this point. 
This contains fabricate() for going back to pseudo-individual data from summary statistics under normality assumptions.  Any fake individual data with the same ("sufficient") summary statistics should give the same results for normal theory methods.  For the curve fits, the normal theory approach is equivalent to least squares.  Other computations may be more-specifically Gaussian.  Theoretically, the results should be computable from the sufficient statistics, but the fake data approach can sometimes be handy.  It is also somewhat obvious how lognormal assumptions can be handled, with reasonable substitutes for sufficient statistics (normal sufficient statistics, but referring to logs.) PROAST is similar in objectives to USEPA Benchmark Dose Software (which is also designed to work from summary statistics.)  Both have a bunch of models.